# Video calibration: why does my laptop show grey instead of green, light blue, and pink?

Tags: video, display, colors, video-streaming, calibration

My laptop has been having this weird behavior with videos, especially if they come from streaming sources. Green objects, such as trees, lawns, and leaves are rendered in grey. Sometimes it happens with youtube videos, but not always. Same thing happens with pink objects like skin, which are rendered in grey as well. Again, the same thing happens with sky blue, which is grey. I wish I had an image to show you. **What could cause this?** The laptop is a few months old and this feature has only just begun to be shown. Thanks.

**EDIT**

This is what my videos look like. In the left image you can see that there is too much grey in the background. The player jumping in the dark shorts has, in reality, blue shorts, which are rendered in grey. In the other image, the painted area in reality is blue, as is the dark jersey. **Why does this happen?** I have even updated my Adobe Flash Player, but to no avail.
[image]

Comment: If its a newer version of windows, there's a built in monitor caliberation tool that works great. This does sound like something you should contact support for - miscaliberations are usually not as bad, but its worth a try

Comment: Windows 8.1. I have been refusing the upgrade for a while...

Comment: Works on 7+ Also sounds a bit like hardware acceleration being wonky

Comment: Something like that can happen with a combination of a few bits of wrong data (be that ram or the network or something else) in combination with the way specific codecs operate, because what you describe happens with badly decoded or corrupted videos . Possibility that a set of filters and/or codecs (for decoding the video) are not fully correct, some codec pack mess, or adjustments.  It would help to know what video was playing (which codec) and if it was going through Flash Player or not.

Comment: How could I check for the codes pack that I have? To see if there's any mess as you suggest... And yes, the videos were going through Flash Player.

Comment: can you add me on skype: my skype name is ekbican

Comment: Done. Are the images telling you something more?

Comment: You can mark this as solved ✔

Comment: As far as I know, nope

Comment: So how to mark it?

Comment: @FC84, you should only mark an answer as accepted if it actually answers your question and you no longer have the problem. If the answer does not, then marking as accepted is unnecessary and really does more harm than good. You don't have to mark any answer if none of them are a solution. Also, if existing answers only guide you to a solution but the full solution needs more steps, it's fully acceptable to add your own more complete answer. (Though you can also choose to comment with the missing steps on an existing answer - your choice.)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should check this out https://pcmonitors.info/articles/using-icc-profiles-in-windows/

I know this is not the absolute solution but I can't leave comments, so I'll leave this as an answer. I hope this will help you mate

Edit: A photograph or video that shows the problem will come in handy

P.s.

You should try to uninstall graphics driver and download the graphics driver from official vendors website (Intel, Nvidia, MSI, Toshiba, Asus, Acer etc.) and install the graphics driver that you downloaded. Then go for a restart and check the problem. If it still persists, there is something wrong with your windows color profiles or your laptops screen. If literally nothing helps, you should call the helpline and ask the procedure of repairing. Then you ask for repair of your laptop and wait the service to fix it, I hope I can help

Edit 2:

You should check your graphics cards preferences, because some gpu's are managing the entire color profile on its own so it's better to look there.

To check your graphics card, simply right click on somewhere blank in your desktop. Then open your graphics card program and go to ' Video / Color Preferences ' part, then look for ' Restore to default settings ' button, then click that button and save the changes. This will solve the problem for sure..

If this trick can't solve your problem, you should bring your laptop to the service, because it might be an hardware issue. But If you want to try to fix more before sending it to repair, you should make a bootable Ubuntu flash disk and boot Ubuntu, see if the problem persists in Ubuntu. If the problem still persists even If in Ubuntu, then it must be a hardware issue which means that you must get it to repair..

Hope these suggestions will solve your problem :) Take care

Comment: Please check my edit. I've added a couple of screenshots. Hope this makes things clear! Thanks!

Comment: @ek.bic, we generally prefer that answers are self-contained as much as possible - which means a minimal reliance on links to external sites. Even if you add just "Your display may be miscalibrated. Try the colour profiles/calibration options in Windows; instructions here <link>", that's already much better and will be far more useful to future readers if the linked site goes down.

Comment: @Bob Now it's an entire solution on it's own :D 